# Use jQuery in the intel xdk init-app.js function for event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, intel-xdk

If anybody could help me with this -
Inside the intel xdk, there is a function for event listeners, something like the following code.

```
app.initEvents = function()
{
    //...
    //...
    var el, evt ;

    if( navigator.msPointerEnabled || !('ontouchend' in window))    // if on Win 8 machine or no touch
        evt = "click" ;                                             // let touch become a click event
    else                                                            // else, assume touch events available
        evt = "touchend" ;                                          // not optimum, but works

    el.addEventListener(evt, myEventHandler, false) ;

    //el.evt(myEventHandler) ;
}
```

This works perfectly, however I would like to use jQuery event binding. So, instead of writing `el.addEventListener(evt, myEventHandler, false)` I would like to write it like this `el.evt(myEventHandler)`.

This does not work. However, if I use `click` instead of `evt`, it works. I see that `evt` represents "click" as a string. So, I am confused, because of "click" and "touchend" strings and doubt whether writing click as in my above jQuery, will work for touch screens.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just use jQuery's [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind events. This will allow you to use a variable as an event name.

```
$(el).on(evt, myEventHandler);
```

I want to say you can just use bracket notation like so:

```
$(el)[evt](myEventHandler);
```

But this is bad and you should feel bad if you use this way.

Comment: Note that the bracket notation will only work for event names for which jQuery has aliased functions. (i.e., jQuery has `$.fn.click` but does not have `$.fn.myCustomEvent`). The `.on` method will work for all and should be used.

Comment: @JAAulde excellent point, custom events or undefined events in jQuery will not respond to the bracket notation.